# Single page application vs Standard MVC more details in post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using kendo for my client side framework using MVVM single page application architecture for a multi page MVC app that I'm currently working on. What happens is there are 4 pages/steps in total in which the first 3 steps requires users to enter in some information and hitting the next button and using kendos router function to route to the specific page on button "Next" press.

Each pages values depends on the previous page, so in page 1 user would enter in some user ID's, on next button click it will call an AJAX call to my controller method passing in a viewmodel from the view and then returning some values based on those ID's and load them on page 2.

Because the values are loaded based on a kendo observable viewmodel from the view on page 1, if the user was to refresh on page 2, the values would all become null since the refresh would basically wipe out all the values saved in the viewmodel or if the user presses the "Previous" button or the back button on the browser whatever values they entered on page 1 would also be empty instead of displaying the previous values they've entered.

**Main question would be is this the right architecture for what I'm doing? Should I just be doing standard MVC and passing my viewmodels/populating my screens from the server side so my values would never be null but on refresh it would just always hit the server side code.**

**If a single page application architecture is fine for such an application what would be some solutions for this problem?**

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use sessionstorage or localstorage to retain those values for however long you want?

Comment: @Marco Yeah I can, but I generally just don't like using those it's kind of just a personal thing, and it seems to be just extra work if I had to do that then wouldn't it just be easier and cleaner to just ditch the single page application way and just use standard MVC by passing my viewmodels around?

It's more of an architecture thing than anything at this point, it's more like should I be doing a single page application with these requirements or just stick to standard MVC?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not in scope for stackoverflow. We cannot solve this kind of question in a proper way. It would all come down to oppionions and your requirements, which we do not know. Personally, this is not a question of architecture, but just of using the right tools asp.net or JavaScript in the browser offer you (Session / Cache and Local Storage). You can use either irrespectively of your architecture.

Comment: @Marco Ahh okay if it if it helps, pretty much my application is an admin tool that lets users specifies a list of user ID's on the first page, when user presses next, it will take them to a page with a kendo grid that will be loaded with user first names and emails based from the list of user id's from the first page. Users are then allowed to make edits to the first names or emails and then hit next, to a final screen which will then submit the info from the grid and save it into the DB. If that makes it more clear?

Comment: @Marco I'm technically just trying to determine if I'm overcomplicating things by doing MVVM with javascript in my situation or it would just be cleaner and more I would say "practical/or a better way" of building my application with just standard MVC procedures by passing the viewmodel to the server side on every call I need to load up my pages via ajax begin form, etc....

Comment: Well then just store that Id in the Uri like `/user/{id}/list/`. Everytime you hit refresh you can take that is from there.

Comment: Personally, yes you overcomplicate. You just need to decide how you want to persist information and how much effort you want to put it. Since you are using a SPA, i'd just go for storage in the browser. If you ever want to implement a server-worker, you can implement more sophisticated caching, which also could give you offline support, if you so desire. There are dozens of ways, which this could be solved, but non that would really help you, without seeing your code and your requirements.

Comment: @Marco Okay cool thanks appreciate the input and advice. Yeah in this case I'd probably just going to use storage in the browser which would be the easiest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm doing something similar using the kendo tabstrip. Each step is a tab with a partial view and corresponding view model. I store the the PK in session and when the user clicks a new tab I POST the current and reload the new one's VM from the database.